# AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification not firing

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am playing video from the url using AVPlayer.  **AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification** is not firing. I have put the breakpoints to check. Below is my code snippet:-

```
    @IBAction func playButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: self.currentSelectedContent.link)!
    moviePlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = moviePlayer

    self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "moviePlayBackFinished", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: self.moviePlayer)
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
    }

}

func moviePlayBackFinished() {
    self.playerViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 24):

According to the docs, the observed object must be the `AVPlayerItem` instance, not the `AVPlayer` itself. Try changing `self.moviePlayer` to `self.moviePlayer.currentItem`.

Comment: Finally a correct answer, this one was tough to find! Many thanx!

Answer (score 5):

the property actionAtItemEnd of AVPlayer is KVO compliant:

```
moviePlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "actionAtItemEnd", options: [], context: nil)


override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "actionAtItemEnd"{
        // 
        print("FINISH")
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387376-actionatitemend

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeractionatitemend

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
selector:#selector(didEndPlayback), 
name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object:nil)
```

Comment: what is `NativeVideoPlayer`?

Comment: Sorry, that was my code which I was using for one of my projects. Edited my answer. You have to write any selector you want to call when the Notification is fired. Please note that the object `nil` is here because this way it would be fired for every item. You can of course specify a single player item here if you want it for only a single item.

Comment: in my case it doesn't work. I just wanted to play the item for one time but it is played in infinite loop

Comment: Looks like some problem with the code in your `didEndPlayback` selector. You can share the code for more help.

Comment: in my case there are multiple players and each of them plays a single file. I don't understand why it happens. But in my case I replaced the existing player handler implementation with my own one. The main difference between these implementations - I don't use `AVPlayerItem` explicitly - the player is initialised with filename directly.